# What OEM Windows 8 licenses exist, and how do I tell which one is installed on my laptop?

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad, license, oem

I plan to purchase a new Lenovo laptop that comes preinstalled with Windows 8 (the exact product statement is `Windows 8 64`). As far as I understand, that's an OEM version.

The problem is that I need to use this laptop not only within the US and I might need to reinstall the OS from scratch in other country. I found out that Windows 8 (without Pro) comes in three flavors:

- Core
- Core Country
- Core Single Language

As I understand, the latter two are limited with their activation ability as well as LP MUI installation. Lenovo states that their laptops [may be regionally locked](http://shop.lenovo.com/ISS_Static/WW/AG/merchandising/US/popups/promos/popup_win8.html).

> Regional Activation:  Use of this product is restricted to a specific region. You may not be able to activate this product outside of such region.

Neither sales nor technical representative was able to tell me which version comes with T430.

How can I find which version is bundled?

P.S. I have the same question regarding 2012-fall Dell computers as well, but didn't try their support yet.

**UPD**: Dell sales representative failed to fulfill my request at the current moment as well as Lenovo's one.
**UPD2**: Dell support was unable to tell me which Windows 8 the New Inspiron 23 Touch will be running as well.

The source of my assumption is the following table:

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell the licenses sold with USA PC's are not restricted, I help with quite a few people on forums from other countries that have purchased their PC in the USA and never had an issue re-installing or activating. The most common problem with this scenario is getting warranty support from the PC manufacturer.

Comment: It appears that "emerging markets" have the restrictions, probably due to the discount price of the license, MS does not want them being sold by 3rd parties in other countries like the US which gets no discount.

Comment: What you say regarding price is correct about Windows, but w/hardware, the situation is directly the opposite. That drives a lot of customers worldwide into US market. Thank you for some sort of relief anyway.

Comment: Can you post a link to the info you found on "Core" "Core Country" "Core Single Language"?

Comment: http://imgur.com/B3V52

Comment: Now that Microsoft is selling their own hardware running W8, hardware does come into play and you may correct, US sold licenses for W8 may not activate in other countries, time will tell when people start complaining about activation.

Comment: What is the source of the screenshot?

Comment: Actually, the source is the Russian site of famous zero-day MSFT leaker WZOR, the image is google-translated, but I'm pretty sure that is's 99% correct (in terms of editions at least). But as I'm planning to get legal Windows 8, I want to be sure in every bit of agreement.

Comment: Post the answer if you ever figure it out..Love those Russian Video's!..http://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#hl=en&spell=1&q=Just+another+day+in+Russia&sa=X&ei=3ZKNUOrBIpLyqwH33oGgBQ&ved=0CCAQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=cd238efcd5bfa751&bpcl=35466521&biw=1326&bih=794

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6265/discussion-between-aberezovskiy-and-moab)

Comment: Please ask one question per question. `What OEM Windows 8 licenses exist, and how do I tell which one is installed on my laptop?` are two questions of which the former is already present on our community (it's been asked several times actually) and the latter is an interesting question so I'd suggest focusing on that one...

Comment: Actually, my question was single and it was later edited by some community member with lots of rep. So drop the second question.